# What is the most simple way to call a php function from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

All the other AJAX examples I have read involve moving data, using html elements and code for older versions of browsers and are not helping me achieve what I want.

I simply need to call a PHP file from JavaScript when a certain condition is met, there is no action and no data returning/moving. What is the most simple way of calling this php file? I also want to try to avoid using jquery if possible.

```
if( condition is met)
{
 // call the PHP file
}
else
{
 // other logic
}
```

Comment: Just create an image/iframe with a `src` pointing to a php file.

Comment: In my opinion, the easier way is using [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method from jQuery

Comment: -1 for failing to understand the principle of HTTP and request reply. Of course it involves "moving" data.

Comment: -1 for the comment above for failing to understand the context of 'no data returning/moving' in the question. Sorry for the joke I couldn't resist...

Comment: @Luizgrs - no offense taken, stupid people often make the mistake you're doing. Eventually you might learn, but it doesn't appear so.

Answer (score 2):

If AJAX and Jquery are out of the options list you may use an iframe.

```
if(condition)
{
    document.getElementById('iframeId').src = 'page.php'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to see the "simplest" answer. Because the easiest one is jquery.

```
    $.post('yourpage.php',{
    var1 : 'something',
    var2 : 'somethingelse'},
function(return){
   //do something
})
```

What is eaier?